# Image gallery with zoom effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to insert a zoom effect into my gallery with HTML, CSS, and js but I don't know how to do it exactly. I would like it to look something like this: https://www.orsay.com/sr-rs/trenc-mantil-840009016000.html

Comment: https://bashooka.com/coding/21-zoom-javascript-libraries-for-web-mobile/

Answer (score 2):

you can use this library

[imgix](https://github.com/imgix/drift)

and there is a [demo](https://imgix.github.io/drift/)

Comment: Thank you my friend :)